# Packages for regression presentation

Tags: r

I have a linear regression model with 20+ variables and am looking for the best way to present my results in R Markdown HTML. Are there any R packages that make significant coefficients stand out and show key output results? I tried the Stargazer package, but it did not seem to work with the HTML output.